# React Router returning blank screen

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Can't seem to figure out what's wrong even browsing through a couple of examples of react-router-dom...

So here's my main page:

```
class MyPage extends Component {
render () {
    return (
        <Aux>
            <NavigationHeader />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/me" exact component={PersonalInfoContainer}/>
                <Route path="/exps" component={ExpsContainer}/>
            </Switch>
            {/* <ExpsContainer /> */}
        </Aux>
    );
}
```

I want to create a page to show some personal info of the user as the `/me` page. So here's the `PersonalInfoContainer`:

```
class PersonalInfoContainer extends Component {
componentDidMount () {
    console.log("PI container: ", this.props);
}

render () {
    return (
        <Aux>
            <Link to={this.props.match.url + '/edit' }>EDIT</Link>
            <Switch>
                    <Route path={this.props.match.url + '/edit'} component={PersonalInfoForm}/>
                    <Route path={this.props.match.url} component={PersonalInfoDetail}/>

            </Switch>
        </Aux>
    )
}
}
```

Here's the problem, what I want to do is have an `EDIT` button that leads to an input form to let users patch their info. I assume with this setup, the link should be `/me/edit`, but no matter I use `Link to={this.props.match.url + '/edit' }` or `Link to={'/edit' }` (which in this case the url is simply `/edit`), it always returns a blank page. I have tested that form component to be working so it really should be something wrong with my routing method.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you surround your code with `BrowserRouter`? I didn't see it in the posted code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did wrap the whole `MyPage` class in BrowserRouter in App.js so I guess that wasn't the problem.